# Python 3, turning csv into a python dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to take a csv file (which can be found here on my GitHub repo, https://github.com/playdscription/100daysofpython/blob/master/day_012/master_exercise_boolean.csv and turn it into a dictionary in python3. The idea is to take a google sheet, have multiple people fill it out, then turn it into a csv and have a python script pack that into a dictionary so I can access this information in a variety of ways.

I open the csv file, make a reader object out of it, then I loop through each line, and loop through each item in a specific part of the line and if the item has a value in it then I want it to write that value to a dictionary I have labeled joint. However even if there is a value in the item, I cannot get it to even just print that value. What am I doing wrong?

```
import csv

exercise_library = {}

joint = {}


with open('/Users/laptop/github/100daysofpython/day_012/master_exercise_boolean.csv' , 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    #look for joint actions of the NECK
    for line in csv_reader:
        for item in line[4:7]:
            if item == True:
                joint[line[3]] = [item]
    #look for joint actions of the scapula.
        for item in line[8:12]:
            if item == True:
                joint[line[7]] = [item]
    #look for joint actions of the glenero_humeral.
        for item in line[13:19]:
            if item == True:
                print(item)
                #joint[line[12]] = [item]

        exercise_library[line[0]] = [joint]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is that create the key names and then assign values to dictionary. Also, items are read as string '1' not boolean, so I have changed that in code below.

```
import csv

exercise_library = {}

joint = {}

colnames = []


with open('test.csv' , 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    counter = 0
    for line in csv_reader:
        if counter==0:
            colnames.append(line[3])
            colnames.append(line[7])
            colnames.append(line[12])
        else:
            for item in line[4:7]:
                if item == '1':
                    joint[colnames[0]] = item
            #look for joint actions of the scapula.
            for item in line[8:12]:
                if item == '1':
                    joint[colnames[1]] = item
            #look for joint actions of the glenero_humeral.
            for item in line[13:19]:
                if item == '1':
                    joint[colnames[2]] = item

            exercise_library[line[0]] = joint
        counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be what you want but this is the way you should do.

```
import csv
import requests
from collections import defaultdict

header = []
data = defaultdict(list)
with open('master_exercise_boolean.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for i, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if i ==0:
            header = line
        else:
            for j, item in enumerate(line):
                if item:
                    data[header[j]].append(item)

print(data)
```